# post form and textarea on one ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to post form and a textarea outside a form, i tried this code but its not working

```
 <script>
  function updateuseracc(form, password)
 {  
var p = document.createElement("input");
var newemail=$("#newemail");
form.appendChild(p);
p.name="p";
p.type="hidden";
p.value=hex_sha512(password.value);
password.value="";


$.post('updateuser.php',$('#myform').serialize(),textarea:textarea).done(function(data){
    alert('Account Successfuly Updated');
    });


 }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it like this

```
$.post('updateuser.php', $('#myform').serialize() + "&textarea=" + textarea).done(function(data) {
    alert('Account Successfuly Updated');
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry it didnt worked, i cant send the textarea value, it just send blank

Comment: great it worked! i made a make the id and the name of the newmail textarea the same. THANKS!Got a lot of more questions coming! Hope there's more smart people like you